# Django Rest Framework and Channels, You cannot call this from an async context

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, django-channels

What i am trying to do is to nest a DRF model serializer into another model serialiser's field like so

```
class username_serial(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']


class game_serial(ModelSerializer):

    user_01 = username_serial()

    class Meta:
        model = game
        fields = ['id','user_01','user_02','is_private','is_accepted']
```

Error :

> Exception inside application: **You cannot call this from an async
> context - use a thread or sync_to_async. Traceback** (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\baza\Desktop\production\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py",
> line 173, in **get**
> rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)   File "C:\Users\baza\Desktop\production\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py",
> line 15, in get_cached_value
> return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name] **KeyError: 'user_01'**

This works normally without Django Chennels because channels is async and i can't use sync code with, works fine by using:

> os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"

In the settings file but it's not a safe approach when it comes to production.
i tried using channel's **database_sync_to_async** as a decorator and as well as a function with a **SerializerMethodField** like so:

```
class game_serial(ModelSerializer):
    user_01 = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user_01(self, obj):
        username = obj.user_01.username

        return str(username)
    class Meta:
        model = game
        fields = ['id','user_01','user_02','is_private','is_accepted']
```

but i get back:

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 23), ('user_01', <coroutine object SyncToAsync.__call__ at 0x0000000005DF6678>), ('user_02', None), ('is_private', False), ('is_accepted', False)]), OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('user_01', <coroutine object SyncToAsync.__call__ at 0
x0000000005DF6D58>), ('user_02', None), ('is_private', False), ('is_accepted', False)])]
```

with an

> Exception inside application: Object of type 'coroutine' is not JSON
> serializable

so i guess that JSON couldn't serialize those "coroutine" objects and normally i should or "want" to get the actual values of them instead.

How can i do the task? any workaround or other methods are welcomed, thank you in advance.

**in consumers.py ..**

```
games = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_games)()
        serialized_games = game_serial(games, many=True)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            'text': json.dumps(serialized_games.data)
        })
def get_games(self):
        return list(game.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Django Channels but I know Django and async.
I'll be honest, I don't like these hacky decorators. And I don't think running such a simple task in a thread is a good idea.

You have an `obj`, so you were able to query the DB earlier. If so, there's a place without async context or async context where accessing the DB works. In the error message `user_01` is not found in the "cached" object from the DB. So just prefetch what you need before.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return game_serial.objects.select_related('user_01')
```

```
class game_serial(ModelSerializer):
    user_01 = serializers.CharField(source='user_01.username')
```

This way you don't have problems with this `sync-to-async` magic, it's more efficient and easier to reason about.

---

EDIT:

I repeat, you should select related where you fetch the data. After you added another example, I can suggest something like that

```
def get_games(self):
    return list(game.objects.select_related('user_01').all())
```

and it will work just fine.

You can also try

```
@database_sync_to_async
def get_games(self):
    return list(game.objects.select_related('user_01').all())
```

and

```
serialized_games = await game_serial(games, many=True)
```

In both cases this serializer will work just fine.

```
class game_serial(ModelSerializer):
    user_01 = serializers.CharField(source='user_01.username')

    class Meta:
        model = game
        fields = ['id','user_01','user_02','is_private','is_accepted']
```

Comment: SerializerMethodField looks for get_{{field_name}} and by default passes the current object as a param, those objects are coming from my APIVIEW in consumers.py

`games = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_games)()
        serialized_games = game_serial(games, many=True)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            'text': json.dumps(serialized_games.data)
        })`

PS: **user_01 = serializers.CharField(source='user_01.username')** didn't work

Comment: Yes, so if you `select_related` in your `APIView` you can use what I wrote or your `SerializerMethodField` as `user_01` will be available in `obj` during the serialization. Show your `APIView` where you are using this serializer.

Comment: sorry i meant consumer and not view

Comment: either way, show where you use this serializer

Comment: i updated the post.
another approach i tried is adding **@property** decorator to game modal that fetches the username, but same error raises.

Comment: works like a charm!, you are a life saver sir, thank you so much.